# Launcher3 not working on Android 7.1.1

Tags: 7.1-nougat

I have a Moto Z Force Droid running Android 7.1.1. Today Launcher3 died repeatedly and wouldn't let me do anything. I found a note that suggested clearing either the cache or the data for the app. I chose to clear the data, and now Launcher3 won't let me place app icons on the main screens. I have to find them on the app list, and a long press shows a series of information buttons on the app instead of letting me place it on a screen. Rebooting to safe mode didn't help.

Any suggestions for (a) fixing this, or (b) getting a new launcher? I tried Evie Launcher and Smart Launcher 3 and didn't like either.

Answer (score 0):

Still shaking my head over this.  Turns out the little balloons that rise up in the app list (and only on certain apps) are IN ADDITION to being able to move the icon to the main screen, via a long press.  After having lunch and calming down, I tried repopulating the main screen and it worked.  Sigh.

Comment: I could repopulate the screen,  as i described, but I want to add some widgets and now launcher3 is dying again every time I try. This is crazy, I need a fix and haven't seen one that doesn't involve rebuilding my entire screen every other day. Help?